# my laptop won't start after installing ati driver 12.04

Tags: drivers

My laptop won't start or turn on any more after
installing Ati driver using that documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD
after doing that step

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

i rebooted and then blank, even screen off I tried swapping 4x2gb ram even removing hard disk but found no solution.

Help me please I have only one thing in my life which is my laptop now seem to be dead .

Comment: Can you acces tty with Ctrl+Alt+F1 ?

Comment: my laptop doing nothing not even reading disk not showing BIOS promt @Xubu-Tur

Comment: If this is true that is not an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: when I turn my laptop on it does show power led & graphic chip heating up but not processor @Xubu-Tur

Comment: I think graphics is corrupt that is the reason it's not turning PC up and showing BIOS

Comment: I have analyzed whole and every hardware of my laptop, nothing's seemed to be burnt then what  could be the cause?  all I know it happened after installing ati drivers @Xubu-Tur I'm not blaming Ubuntu I'm asking for solution

Comment: nothing impossible there might be a solution. we have not understand  the fact that's actually have impact @Xubu-Tur

Comment: Which Laptop model did you have? Did you try an external display? Did you follow the troubleshoot in the manual?

Comment: it's dell inspiron 1564 @Xubu-Tur

Comment: still no solution I'm education less since this happened I don't know what to do I'm hypertension

Comment: Perhaps its better to ask on a hardware forum... or write to the dell support.

Comment: Dear #Tuknutx it's. Been confirmed that's graphics issue either it's not faulty but just it preprogram firmware removed while doing step of given link in question I request plz help find solution it's very complicated to search solution using mobile also computer technian have escaleted the same issue nd trying to solve but it's been a week he couldn't solve it's I thing it's very easy to solve if we get the knowledge indeed it's not rocket science